# DIY solution for recording breathing sounds?

Tags: microphone, contact-mic, breathing

I need a budget solution for recording breathing sounds. What options can you suggest?

Would, for example, a simple contact mic (placed on the person's chest) be suitable for this?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: current answer & comment taken into consideration - do you want the 'outside' sound or the 'inside' [of the human body]? Any mic can get something of the 'outside', you might need something specialist if you need 'what the doctor hears through his stethoscope' [or put a pillow over any sensitive mic taped to the chest]

Comment: as an experiment, preferably something from the 'inside' (thanks for pointing out that it wasn't clear). the pillow is a good idea, i'll try this for sure.

Comment: if you really want the 'stethoscope' sound, you may actually have to try a real stethoscope, with a tiny lav mic taped to the listening end. [It's not something I've ever tried, but extraneous noise is likely to be a major issue]

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: dues to the nature of SE, it's unlikely you'll ever find out, if the voter didn't also leave a comment. [wasn't me, btw;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a normal mic for that. Pretty much any portable recorder should work for you, from zoom H1 up. Even a $20 computer mic would probably give you something useful, especially if the perspective is close.

Comment: thanks! so a contact mic would not give any advantages? (i started to read about them and looks like it's something i want to experiment with some day.)